# gcloud PubSub library for embedded devices

Tags: node.js, embedded, publish-subscribe, iot, gcloud

I am working on IoT project over google cloud. I use Publish/Subscribe to allow devices contact each others. I developed the backend system using nodejs, then I will develop Mobile app that will use google library to publish/subscribe.

The problem that I face now is that. Does google have any C/C++ Library for contacting PubSub/googlecloud API or not, and if not, is there any alternative way to keep embedded devices (programmed in C/C++) updated with mobile applications actions.

Note: I need real-time control between mobile app and embedded device.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Cloud Pub/Sub has a [HTTP/JSON based API](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs) (under the **API Reference** tag in the sidebar), so you can roll your own library in this case.

The client APIs that Google currently supports are listed [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcloud-common). If you can run Go or Java on your embedded device (both a lot less common than C/C++ on embedded devices, and usually only supported if you stretch the definition of "embedded"), you can have a fully-supported client library.

Comment: It sounds good, thanks for your answer.

But, What If I used the broker link from PubSub and implemented my own MQTT implementation, is that available ??

Thanks.

Comment: Are you referring to [this](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-pubsub-mqtt-proxy)? I don't see why not.